# Neovim:Background color doesn't fill terminal window

Tags: neovim

I recently set my nvim theme to [PaperColor](https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme/) but after following the instructions and setting my background color to `dark` it leaves some dead space at the bottom and on the right.Here is a screenshot.[image: visible dark borders]

My .vimrc is in the screenshot.How can i remove the dead space? I'm using gnome-terminal and NeoVim v0.2.2

Comment: It would be nice if you could run neovim without any configuration (`nvim -u NONE`) then just execute the `colorscheme` command and tell us what is the result. I don't have this colorscheme so I cannot do it on my machine.

Comment: The color scheme is [here](https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme).I have run neovim with `nvim -u NONE` and colorscheme command returns default even though I have changed the colorscheme to papercolor.

Comment: sorry I meant "execute command `colorscheme PaperColor`". starting vim with `-u NONE` starts it with no configuration.